# Overriding onContextItemSelected() in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a class that extends SherlockActivity because I'm using an ActionBarSherlock action bar in the activity. However, I'm also trying to add a context menu to a listview in this activity that launches when an item in the listview is longpressed. I'm getting an error in my declaration of `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` that says that my override is invalid because there's nothing to override. However, when I remove the override, the function is never called. I know this has something to do with the way SherlockActivity inherits from Activity but I'm not sure about the specifics. Maybe I'm missing an import? See the relevant code here:

```
public class Inbox extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inbox);
    refreshMsgs(this.getCurrentFocus());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.lstInbox){
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        String contactName = lstConversation.get(info.position).getContactName();   
        menu.setHeaderTitle(contactName);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "View contact");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Delete thread");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    SmsConversation selectedConvo = lstConversation.get(info.position);         

    if (item.getItemId() == 0){
        //view contact
        Intent viewcontactIntent = new Intent();
        String contactId = selectedConvo.getContactId();
        Uri uriContact = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        viewcontactIntent.setData(uriContact);
        PendingIntent pViewIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 1, viewcontactIntent, 0);
        try {
            pViewIntent.send();
        } catch (CanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
      //DELETE thread
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

And here are all of my imports for the class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.PendingIntent.CanceledException;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Faced with a similar issue a long time ago, I have overriden `onContextItemSelected()` by forcing the normal `MenuItem` using its fully qualified class name (`android.view.MenuItem`), like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected (android.view.MenuItem item)
{
  //implementation
}
```

Comment: Yep! These use two different `MenuItem` classes so one of the method signatures must use the fully-qualified class name.

Comment: @JakeWharton glad to see you're actively checking the ABS tag! Any chance you can tell us why this method doesn't get implemented by ABS? I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/OBhjAV_3nHw/YfhPBjeBd-gJ) discussion, but you just mention that the fully qualified name needs to be used.

Comment: It's been around since API 1 and there no real functionality change for ABS to implement. In retrospect I probably should have named the ABS `MenuItem` as `SherlockMenuItem` to avoid problems like this.

Comment: @A--C Thanks, that solved it. I had a feeling it was something like this.